# If $\sum a_n^{3/2}$ is convergent then $\sum \frac{a_n}n$ is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> If $\sum a_n^{3/2}$ is convergent then $\sum \frac{a_n}n$ is convergent.

To prove this result: How to approach ?

Actually, when I first encountered this problem, I  searched  for an example that would counter this claim.

But I only have the usual example of harmonic series.

Hint only, please.

Comment: Is $(a_n)$ assumed positive?

Comment: Yes a_n >0 .Because other wise by alternating test directly we can argue.

Comment: Young's inequality $xy\le x^p/p+y^q/q$, valid for positive $x,y,p,q$ where $1/p+1/q=1$, is useful here.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Holder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality) to deduce that 
$$
\sum_{n} \frac{a_n}{n}\leq \left(\sum_n a_n^{3/2}\right)^{2/3}\left(\sum_n \frac{1}{n^3}\right)^{1/3}
$$

Answer (score 2):

One does not need to use Holder, Young, or anything else that advanced. The part of the series in the RHS corresponding to those $n$ with $a_n<\frac1{n^2}$ converges since $a_n<\frac1{n^2}$ yields $\frac{a_n}n<\frac1{n^3}$, the part corresponding to those $n$ with $a_n\ge\frac1{n^2}$ converges since in this case $\frac{a_n}n\le a_n^{3/2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Your thought of the harmonic series is a good one.  If $a_n$ is nice enough, you can say $a_n^{3/2} \lt \frac 1n$, so $\frac {a_n}n \lt n^{-5/3}$.  Of course, you were not given that $a_n$ is nice, so there is still work to do.

Comment: This seems at most a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Note first that, for $a_1,\ldots,a_n\ge 0$, according to Hölder's inequality
$$
\frac{a_1}{1}+\frac{a_2}{2}+\cdots+\frac{a_n}{n}\le (a_1^p+\cdots+a_n^p)^{1/p}
\left(\frac{1}{1^q}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^q}\right)^{1/q}
$$
whenever $\displaystyle \frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. In particular, for $p=3/2$ and $q=3$, we have
$$
\frac{a_1}{1}+\frac{a_2}{2}+\cdots+\frac{a_n}{n}\le (a_1^{3/2}+\cdots+a_n^{3/2})^{2/3}
\left(\frac{1}{1^3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^3}\right)^{1/3}\le \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^{3/2}\right)^{2/3}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^3}\right)^{1/3}=M<\infty.
$$
Hence, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{n}$ converges.